# Geometry Nodes Align to Curve/Face Problem

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am having a real problem figuring out how to fix this. I have instanced an object along a curve and applied the rotation of each point, but the corners average the angle of the segment before and after. I need these objects to aim directly at the next point in the curve so there are right angles and connected rather than these 45˚ oriented objects with open gaps, but I cannot figure out how to get that data into the geometry nodes. This same problem occurs if I use a mesh, so that's not a solution. I essentially need the normal of each segment along the curve, not the point's, which averages the normal from both adjacent segments.

[image]

Comment: would you mind sharing your blend file using https://pasteall.org/blend/ ?

Comment: One way would be to duplicate the path and feed it through the Curve Trim node, then adjusting the Fac to be between 0.001 and 0.999 so that the instance does not reach the end of the curve. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Perhaps the answere here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245282/how-to-bend-geometry-with-geometry-nodes Can help?

Comment: If your question was solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted Answer". This will make it easier for others to see which way leads to the solution, and the question will no longer appear as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still didn't get a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 3):

First, I would put the pivot point of the wall panel on the *Y-axis* at its center so you don't have to instantiate it at the endpoints.

Then I would simply subdivide the curve once with the node `Subdivide Curve`.

If you then use `Instance on Points`, but only instantiate at every second point by applying the math node `Modulo`, you can directly use the normals of the points.

The node `Align Euler to Vector` makes a suitable rotation out of it.

[image]

[image]