# Geometry Nodes - Curve driving position of separate curve

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

Is there a way to make a curve follow the path of another curve solely in geometry nodes? I am attempting to wrap a spiral curve around a circle curve and am unsure on how to bend the spiral curve to follow a separate path. My goal is to create a torus with the circle curve with curve to mesh and then join that with a curve to mesh of the wrapped spiral curve so that I have a torus with a small wire coiling around it. If there's a better method than using curve nodes I'd be happy to change my approach.

Outside of geo nodes, I can use a curve modifier to achieve this effect but I'd prefer to have this integrated into my node network.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It just so happens I recently made a limited *Curve* modifier equivalent in GN, to answer [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/245282/35559).

It can be used, for example, like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oops, Mis-labelled the  top _Value_  input node. That should be 'Turns'.