# Array + Curve + Subdiv anomaly

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, curve-modifier

I have an array of subdivided cubes, which follow a bezier-curve through a curve modifier. The individual meshes of the array are merged.
The issue:
Ordering the modifier stack like this (right):

- Array
- Subdiv
- Curve

Provides the desired, smooth result.

Ordering the Stack like this (left):

- Array
- Curve
- Subdiv

Does not correctly work. The subdiv-modifier seems to "skip" the sections, in which the individual array-elements were merged.

Now, the core issue is, that I do not want to apply the subdiv-modifier bevore the curve and array modifier, as I need to add to the mesh after applying these two. Subdividing beforehand would make a mess.

Screenshot:
[image]

Demo file to reproduce the phenomenon:
https://blend-exchange.com/b/kMJGPQGk

Comment: The problem is caused by internal faces which stop subdivision from smoothing the mesh. No smoothing is needed where the internal faces exist before the curve modifier, so using subdivision before curve yields a smooth result.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady After checking again, I can confirm, that that is indeed the cause of the problem. After deleting the faces in question, everything is as desired. Now, this begs the question, as to what is causing this. Applying the mofifier stack in the (right) order, I still found the internal faces to be present. The difference is, that they have been "catmarked" correctly, whereas the ones in the other stack were not. Why is that the case?

Comment: The internal face works like a holding loop, stopping the subdivision from interpolating between them. See what happens when you put an internal face diagonally, it then also stops the interpolation where the face connects: https://i.imgur.com/sAcPfAp.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want smooth shading, set it now (otherwise remember to set it on the object and caps), duplicate it, remove modifiers from it and name it `Start`, duplicate it again and name it `End`. Go to the original object's *Array* modifier and set the caps accordingly. Edit the mesh and remove the faces where the instances connect. Edit the `End` mesh and remove everything except the face that connects. You will need to flip its normals <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>. Do the same for the `Start` - keep in mind that there it's the opposite face. If you got it wrong, just rename the objects and swap them in the Array modifier.

Answer (score 4):

As you have noted in your comments, internal faces create an anomaly in the normals of the external surface, in both cases. It's less apparent where the *Subdiv* is before the *Curve*.

The *Curve* deforms the array of elements. In a polygonal modelling system, it can do this only by moving vertices to conform to the curve. If the displacement is made *before* the subdivision, only the ends of the box-elements are available to be deformed, and so the curve is approximated by element-length straight-line segments. The *Subdiv*. *then* subdivides those.

If the *Subdiv* comes first, there are more vertices available for *Curve* to deform. Now the curve is approximated by [element-subdivided] length straight-line segments, which are shorter, and approximate the curve more closely. In particular, the normals at the ends of adjacent elements are more alike, and so the joins look smoother.

Some options:

- Get rid of the internal faces: you can cap the ends after applying the *Array* and *Curve* modifiers, or set caps on the array [as suggested by MVB](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245965/35559)
- Manually subdivide the box in its length before deforming, or just make the elements shorter.
- Use a profile: (a rectangular curve,) as a Bevel Object for the sweep curve itself, (in its own *Data* tab, *Geometry* panel,) rather than arraying a mesh down it.

BTW, you may save yourself a lot of trouble by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> applying the scales of your curve and box, before going further. (You would also then have to reset the radius of the curve to 1.) While modelling, *always* scale the *mesh* in Edit Mode, rather than the *object* in Object Mode, (or apply the scale as soon as possible.)

Comment: This provides great inside into the workings of the modifiers! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Geometry Nodes

The size of the node tree is somewhat ridiculous, but it was my first try at geo nodes. Other than some clever optimizations like the concise dimension coming from the bounding box that I learned from [Robin Betts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245553/60486), I might be missing some idiomatic solutions like using an [instance index](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/245996/60486) instead of doing multiplications and comparisons on face indices.

[image]

This recreates the array modifier and removes internal faces based on normals. The *Normal > Separate XYZ > Greater/Less Than* node chains could be replaced with a comparison with a material number for example. *Weld* modifier is required afterwards to get correct subdivision and shading.

[image]