# Deforme (curve) a mesh with blender geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, curve-modifier

I am trying to deform (curve) a mesh using geometry nodes, what I want to achieve is the same operation as the Curves modifier but I want to do everything with my geometry node modifier.
Unfortunately I'm not succeeding, is this possible with geometry nodes?

Comment: Check out https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245553/35559. The _Curve Deform_ Group can be used with any sufficiently subdivided geometry, not just arrays.

Comment: @RobinBetts: Thank you for the suggestion, this works fine. Please post this as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Maybe late, but for the people still looking for this I made a [geo nodes setup](https://marianobasti.gumroad.com/l/followcurvegeonodes) that works as the curve deform modifier.