# Geometry nodes - Scale using specific Vertices

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes

I'm currently using a "Curve Circle" node and an "Instance on Points" Node to create a ring shape. However I can't seem to join up the outer vertices. I tried using a "Merge by Distance" node however that causes other problems due to the distance of the vertices.

What I'd like to be able to do is scale the objects at specific vertices so that they are close enough to use the "Merge by Distance" node.

I suspect that I need to make use of Vertex groups but once I've created my selection of vertices into a group I have no idea how to use them in geometry nodes to achieve my goal.

[image]

For clarity I'm trying to perform the below action procedurally using Geometry Nodes.
[image]

Comment: A merge by distance (or weld) would work for what you're showing.  Is it possible that this image is only a demonstration of the problem on something more complex?  I'd recommend showing your actual problem if it is, as that can impact the solutions.  In general, I'd suggest checking out https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251929/how-to-implement-radius-in-a-geo-nodes-curve-modifier so you can actually curve your instances around the curve rather than merging verts, but I can imagine that the real, actual problem matters.

Comment: I'd also like to take a look at your Geometry nodes set up if you could include a screenshot, or a link to your .blend file?

Comment: Oops, wrong link.  Try https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245282/how-to-bend-geometry-with-geometry-nodes/245553?noredirect=1#comment428782_245553 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have a circular array of elements, you could scale them by the distance to the center point like this:

[image]

[image]

and if you don't want to scale it on z you can use this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you so much for the solution and the clear images. I've done some testing and I think that this will slot in nicely with all the other logic.

Comment: Thank you and you are welcome‼️‼️

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I would do it like that. You can also use the index.