# How can I align the tilt of a curve to that of the nearest surface normal of a mesh?

Tags: geometry, geometry-nodes, mathematics

I guess my question is the same as the one asked here:

[How can I align the tilt of a GN generated curve to the nearest surface normal of a target?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252467/how-can-i-align-the-tilt-of-a-gn-generated-curve-to-the-nearest-surface-normal-o) Although the answer that the op posted appears not to be quite working (not sure what  it does, but it certainly does not align the curve to the surface normals of the mesh)?

Basically I have a curve, that in my case is "shrinkwrapped" (using proximity node) onto a mesh, what Im looking to do is then have a quad strip array along that curve angled along the face normal of the mesh its "shrinkwrapped" onto.

Ive made some progress already based on answers Ive found here on stackexchange, but I cant quite figure out how to control the tilt of the curve so that it matches that of the face normal. Any help appreciated.

This is the blend file Im working with in caes anyone wanna solve the puzzle directly in place, Ive pointed an arrow to a node group that would ideally be modified to become functional):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recently used this setup to align a curve to the surface of a mesh:
It samples the surface normal at each control point and rotates the current normal to the projected mesh normal. Hope this still helps!

[image]