# Deforming instances

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to make a node that wraps spirals along a curve. It needs to be able to work with another instance of itself as input (spirals along spirals along spirals...).
Input here is a bezier curve.
[image: Root node]

Problem is that the second level of spirals is wrapped around the first as if it was a single curve. Continuing from endpoint to starting point without terminating.
The first instance of Spirals along curve outputs three curves spiraling along the input curve. The second instance wraps six spirals along each of those three.
[image: Output]

Here is what the spirals along curve node looks like.
[image: Spirals along curve]

X_Curve_Deform is from [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245553/23632) answer.
I believe my problem is that I realize the instances before deforming. But X_Curve_Deform does not seem to work with instances. This is my first time using geometry nodes and I don't understand how X_Curve_Deform works well enough to make it work on instances.

I am trying to make Spirals along curve a reusable tool.
Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**Edit 2.**

Ok. So you need to cut the lines. I added a bunch of nodes here to increase the number of lines, because you have to use separate lines for each guide segment:

[image]

Next, you cannot relay on X coordinate. I don't know why you want to deform along the path each time, but if you want to - you should replace x coordinate by index

[image]

But after doing this, I still have some glitches.

[image]

**Edit.**

So the problem is that you want to wrap an object on several curves, not one.

So you could probably reverse every second curve:

[image]

**Old answer:**

X curve deform should be executed one time at the end, not twice, like you did. You have putted it inside a node group and use this group several times, which was led to unexpected results.

[image]

Remove X curve deform from node group and put it right before GN output like in my screenshot.

Comment: Don't know why someone downvoted this answer. I tried it and it looks like the solution in my opinion. I wish that someone would explain what he doesn't like about it. Maybe it can be edited so a downvote is not necessary.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I don't know why, either.. it's pretty much the answer I was about to give! Just noting... X_Deform maps  **X**  to the curve, Y and Z to its orthogonals.. so if the object is already off X, it will wander.

Comment: @RobinBetts Maybe just some malignant troll running around, downvoting others. I just had two of my older answers (which have no connected subjects) downvoted within a minute yesterday.

Comment: This is not the solution. There should be three of those bundles spiraling along the curve. This ignores the first instance of spirals along curve. I want to be able to do this in multiple stages with spirals along spirals etc.

Comment: @John What about adding another _Spirals Along Curve_ node group like you have two already, just with different settings? Your question seemed as if you didn't like the connection between start and end point. This answer solved it. Simple downvoting only decreases reputation and doesn't point in the direction you want the answer to go to - so others with similar ideas won't even bother to answer because it seems they are completely wrong, and it won't encourage the one answering to help you with future questions.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann The problem is the connection between start and end point. But this answer changes the function of Spirals along curve. Adding more instances will only create more spirals along the first input curve. What I want is for there to be three spirals along the input curve and six spirals along each of those three. I want to be able to do this in several steps. I have removed my downvote.

Comment: @John Maybe you should elaborate your question a bit further so that people who are not reading all the comments will get that information, too.

Comment: Reversing every other spiral still connects the ends. The connecting ends are just closer together.

Comment: Of course, because you have **one** solid set of curves distributed along **more than one** guide curves!

Comment: @Crantiz Exactly. It would be great if Spirals along curve would output instances rather than combining the spirals to a single curve.

Comment: I think it would be problematic to get Edit 2 to work on even more instances of spirals along curve. At the moment it only works for certain values of the count parameter. I deform along X mainly because i found that solution elsewhere. But using index instead makes it a little harder to get the pitch parameter accurate (it is already wrong since curve length gives the total length of all spirals in the curve). I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: If you want to use X coordinate to deform along the path, you should keep it unreformed along the original path and deform it at the end like in my first suggestion

Comment: does anybody know why a curve to mesh node with curve circle doesn't work here if i add this add before group output? -> i downloaded the blend file and tried it there