# Geometry nodes, Arc curve to mesh endpoints dont align

Tags: workflow, geometry-nodes

I am trying to make a continuous loop from a few arc curves but when I do a curve to mesh with a curve cicle, the end faces dont align. This example has two arcs but I actually want to do 10 or more.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Perhaps if you described your goal rather than your current approach we might be able to work out a better way to solve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [quellenform](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/145249/quellenform) commented, multiple splines won't align, but you can recalculate the ends or even the entire thing.

The reason for the misalignment is that the direction used to generate a profile curve in a point of the main curve is the interpolated value from the two adjacent edges, but in the ends of the curve there is only a single edge.

If you or someone else wants a Geo Nodes to fillet a curve with a true arc, here's one I did:

[image]

[image: Geometry Nodes arc fillet]

[image: Arc fillet custom node]

[image: Arc fillet no misalignment]

Comment: This is perfect, looks like this is what i was looking for, Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I love [Hulifier's](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/127847/hulifier) interpretation of my idea, but what I love even more are simple solutions:

**Why would you calculate the angle of the ends when Blender has already done that for you?**

This image shows four arcs that were extruded using `Curve to Mesh`:

[image]

After all, since we have all the necessary information in hand when creating the arc and the profile, all you have to do is the following:

- Calculate the angle of one segment
- Select the points of the mesh at the ends
- Transfer the positions of the points of the second profile segment (because it already has the correct rotation)
- Rotate the positions of the end points according to the angle of a segment

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not, Indeed?

Comment: @RobinBetts Why not a simple solution, or why not calculate everything manually?

Comment: Why not be simple? :D I'm just about to post an inferior answer :

Answer (score 3):

if i understood you right, you just want them to align, and not "one" curve, so you could just increase the resolution of your arc to a high number and the align pretty well:

[image]

Comment: Yes it is better but not perfect.

Comment: yes of course, because the arc will be divided into pieces (defined by resolution) and Blender calculates from that "piece" the angle so it had to be infinite to get a perfect right angle. But  - just my opinion - if you make it high enough you won't see it in render...and you can push it really high... ;) just my opinion

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could wheel out the ol' [Curve Deform group](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245553/35559) (simplified a bit), and use it to deform a prism of an appropriate length, given arc-span and arc-radius, then rotate the whole thing to the start-angle:

[image]

Here used to demo with the fixed default resolutions illustrated above:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am always amazed at the variety of solution possibilities when Geometry Nodes are in play +1