# How can I make the mesh deform according to the curve?

Tags: modifiers

[image]

As shown above, is there such a modifier in blender that affects the effect of the mesh through the curve, and can also adjust the attenuation of the influence distance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few projections, but so far, have found the smoothest result was by using the X Curve Deform GN group discussed [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245553/35559).

The mesh's proximity to the curve is measured after deformation by that group, and a mapping of the distance is used to mix between the deformed mesh and its original state.

[image]

The *Map Range* maps the distance to 0-1, and the *Float Curve* can the adjust the shape of the fall-off.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thanks for your help.
This is exactly what I want, by tweaking the mapping curve to gain control over the falloff distance.
Thanks again!