# Geometry nodes: sampling Z position from curve to mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a mesh that I want to bend along the curve, then move all vertices to match its Z position. Here's the process:

1. Mesh in X length of the curve
2. Bend the mesh to curve on XY plane
3. Align mesh's Z positions to the curve, using the X position from step 1 for curve length sampling.
   [image: Process]
   And there's a problem - the mesh is not properly aligned with curve, depending on the angle it's too low or too high. I assume I have to correct the X length input for sampling, but I have no idea how to do this.

Edit: the blend with the case: https://blend-exchange.com/b/Pav9wL2L

Comment: I need to bend an existing mesh

Comment: However, the mesh you show here can be easily constructed with Geometry Nodes. Or is it actually a more complex mesh?

Comment: It's complex mesh - I want to bend any input mesh possible, so I can't generate it from curve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to bend geometry with geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245282/how-to-bend-geometry-with-geometry-nodes)

Comment: I'm using that method for the step 2, but for step 3 I need to only bend Z positions, while this method would rotate the whole mesh.

Comment: I don't understand the part about "bend Z positions". Can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: That means I add Z position to the target mesh from the curve to align the curve on Z position, only Z position, without rotating the mesh

Comment: @quellenform it's a 'Z Up' deformation I think.. One route: capture curve Z, flatten curve, deform mesh to flat curve, offset by captured Z. You or me?

Comment: @RobinBetts Yes, that could be so. But could also be different ...I still don't understand it exactly :D

Comment: @quellenform will give it a shot

Comment: @quellenform Here's the blend file https://blend-exchange.com/b/Pav9wL2L

Comment: @UserNoRandomNumber OK, here's another version. Hope it's getting there. See Edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you're after.. it's just an adaptation of the *X Curve Deform* group from [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245553/35559), which you say you are using, changing the mapping in the curve's coordinates.

- X to the position on the curve
- Y to the cross-product of the curve tangent with (0,0,1), flat to XY, at right-angles to the tangent
- Z to (0,0,1)

The new arrangement is shown below:

[image]

The result:

[image]

It would be simpler to adjust the tilt to make the curve 'Z Up'.. figuring that one out, unless @quellenform gets there first :)

You could take this futher in the mesh, by, for example, flattening the tops of the turrets to XY

[image]

Comment: Well, @RobinBetts, you have taken the cake once again ;-)

Comment: @quellenform Unless I can figure it, I'll post the 'Z-up' Q as one of my own.. just an invitation to have think about it :D

Comment: It works well on the spiral, but on other curves it's getting misaligned [image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/856944439045259316/991781200777723995/unknown.png)

Comment: @UserNoRandomNumber See Edit