# Problem with rotation along curve Geometry Node

Tags: geometry, geometry-nodes

I want those cylinder segments to be perpendicular along the curve. This geometry node is making the segments a bit tilted towards joints.

[image: Geometry Node Problem]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245282/how-to-bend-geometry-with-geometry-nodes/245553#245553 
The answer to this question should be what you are looking for

Comment: @Eneary Good idea, but this does something completely different. Here we are looking for a solution that does not take over the rotation of individual curve points, but aligns the rotation along the straight line. Resampling creates new points, and thus a rotation which deviates from the mesh created in parallel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the node `Resample Curve` creates new points along the curve with new tangents and normals, you always get interpolated values.

These are of course useless for your project, but there is a solution:

Just append the node `Resample Curve` before and increase the subdivision of the curve. Alternatively you can use `Subdivide Curve`.

This will give you enough intermediate points, avoiding interpolation at the crucial points:

[image]

Additionally you can use the node `Curve to Points` for your project. This will directly give you the correct rotation for your instances.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a bit over-elaborate.. but if you want to position your instances by resampling the curve, this is  a possible strategy to suppress interpolation.

- On another branch, convert the curve to a mesh with a simple line, (an extrusion) recording the end which lies on the curve.
- Split the mesh edges
- Delete the edge not on the curve

Now you have set of split mesh lines, exactly coincident with the evaluated curve-segments

- From which you can transfer the edge-direction, by proximity.

[image]

Which makes this difference:

[image]

You could improve this by grouping to a suitable interface.. maybe Curve >  'Segment Tangent'?

[image]