# Move curve along another with Geometry Nodes

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I have two curves: one - spiral with, let's say, 100 control points, and the second one - line with 20 points. Now, I want to move the yellow curve along spiral with geometry nodes. How to do this? I know how to instance on points etc, it is not a problem. Instead I just want to move all the yellow one to the top of the spiral. I think that I have to offset the position of the first yellow control point to the second, and so on, of the spiral, but don't know how exactly.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could e.g. use this node setup:

[image]

to get this:

[image]

be aware: I am using the newest 3.5 Blender alpha version - so there is no transfer attribute anymore. It was replaced by 3 other nodes. That's why i use "sample index" node here. But of course you can achieve the same result with the transfer attributes node on an older version of Blender.

Comment: thank you for your quick solution.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure you can point out your exceptional use-case, (if so, ignore this answer)... but in general, wouldn't  it be simpler to generate your 20-point curve **from** your 100-point curve, than to deform your 20-point curve **to** your 100-point curve?

Some elaboration of this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, it seems an interesting solution. For sure it may be useful, but what I want to do is to build a separate object and simulate inserting this object into the spiral torus. So the solution of @Chris for me would be better. Anyway, your approach is nice and smart, thanks.

Comment: @mptaurus Okydoky. For deforming arbitrary geometry along a curve, [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245553/35559) may be of interest. :)