# Geometry Nodes: Instances flicker when curve modifier is used on top of geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

How can I make the instances not to flicker like this?

[image]

The setup is very basic:

[image]

What is important is that the instances in my real work file have only one material with a texture that use the cube UVs, so I can't use different materials or realize instances node, I think...

[image]

Comment: The problem is that you sample your instance after the mesh is deformed by the curve...
You can use this instead: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245282/how-to-bend-geometry-with-geometry-nodes/245553#245553
Like this: https://blend-exchange.com/b/XxzVyPnk/

Comment: @FredI.R.Thank you! I also got one, perhaps a bit simpler, solution - I'll post it as an answer here

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine gave one solution.

Two GN modifiers are needed:

[image]

First one:

[image]

Second one:

[image]

A little hassle but works!

EDIT:

If you want the large object to keep its UVs, do this:

[image]