# Achieve similar effect as curve modifier in Geometry Node

Tags: geometry-nodes, curve-modifier

Here's the problem I have with geometry node:
[image]

And here's the effect I wanted to achieve in geometry node:
[image]
So basically is there a nodesetup that allows me to make the distributed instance/mesh following the deformation along the curve?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245553/165102

Comment: Could you please supplement your question with a screenshot of your nodes or share your blend file? It would be important to know how you built this. For example, if you use the solution @shmuel posted, you would achieve an even distribution, but it would also distort the frames of the windows. Are you building all this with geometry nodes, or how did you construct it?